# I have put up two views in storyboard, how do I pass an NSString from one view to another?

Tags: objective-c

C gurus,

Is there a way to simply pass an object from one ViewController to another? I searched on the web, however they all use seperate .nib files. Is there a way to implement passing in storyboard?

Thanks for help!

Comment: just use `prepareForSegue:sender:` method for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have, in fact, recently written an article about this. As Aalok said, using `prepareForSegue:sender:` will do the trick.

Check out [the article](http://www.lwxted.com/blog/2012/pass-objects-between-viewcontrollers-objective-c/) for a detailed explanation if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks, the tutorial is detailed and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

just use prepareForSegue:sender: method for it in this method sender can pass any data to the destination controller

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"CONTROLLER's IDENTIFIER DEFINED IN STORYBOARD"]) {
        (TARGETED CONTROLLER)ImageViewController *ivc = (ImageViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
 //ANY VARIABLE WANT TO INITIALIZE       
ivc.capturedImg = image;
}
```